# MySQL lock write table with node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a list of messages, there are several sender agents that reads a batch of 100 messages from list and immediately updates the `inProgress` flag, so other agents will never select them. I do this task with `LOCK TABLES msgList WRITE` and after selecting and updating `UNLOCK TABLES`, I can't use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` because this will not avoid other agents to select common rows.
I did with PHP, now I'm rewriting my program with js on node.js, but I did not find any solution on node.js (node-mysql). Is there any way to lock table on node.js?

Comment: Did you try to execute query `LOCK TABLES msgList WRITE`? What was the result?

Comment: @madox2 I'm using it in my php code, what do you mean?

Comment: `connection.query('LOCK TABLES msgList WRITE', ...`

Comment: @madox2 ok, I have a callback here, that I can select and in its callback rise the flag. when and where I should run `unlock`?